# paginate and display data retrieved remotely in laravel

Tags: php, laravel, pagination, laravel-5.8

i need to display paginated list of items on a laravel blade. I have very little knowledge of laravel and php. basically Controller action will fetch data from web api, and return data retrieved to a blade view. clicking the next/previous buttons should trigger same controller action with page number/index

```
public function displayPaginatedData($pageIndex)
{
    $pageIndex = isset($pageIndex) ? $pageIndex : 1;
    $remoteData = remoteApiProvider::getData($pageIndex); //associative array
    return view('aBlade', $remoteData);
}
```

I read that i can [manually create a `paginator`](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/pagination#manually-creating-a-paginator) via `Illuminate\Pagination\Paginator` but i cannot provide the full array, too big. is there an interface that i can implement to utilize this laravel pagination + `links()` api?

Comment: Enjoy: https://youtu.be/4yfRdl2-3mE

Comment: i've been through tons of tutorials, blogs and docs. all covering very basic usage.

Comment: okay what is so complex about your use case? I don't understand. Your question describes basic pagination

Comment: basic pagination requires `Query Builder` or `Eloquent query`. wait! those two must implement an interface to work with pagination. perhaps this is the way to go.

Comment: I really don't understand why you aren't using Laravel's built in kit to do this. I assume Laravel's implementation doesn't really use an "interface", it merely alters the ranges of the select based on a page number. What do you actually need? Because I still don't understand

Comment: i want to use laravel's built in pagination. `remoteApiProvider.getData()` returns associative array. not a `query builder` nor `Eloquent query`

Comment: Ohh I see, you want to paginate some independent data that isn't from your database via a model? If so, look at some tutourials on pagination raw php and put your mind to it and you will be able to do it. StackOverflow won't write your code for you, go and have a go, if you can't do it, provide all your relevant code in all relevant files and post a new more specific question